# What does "net use /HOME" actually do?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, home-directory

The documentation states

```
Connects a user to their home directory.
```

The notion of a "home directory" isn't really something I'm used to in a Windows environment. Obvious web searches didn't turn up anything useful for me.

I really also don't want to "just try it" right now as I'm in somewhat of a delicate domain-client setup and this option sounds like it interfere.

Comment: users do have home directories - its under /users/ in windows 7 and something else in windows XP. Likewise you can have home folders on a fileshare. Its just not in the consciousness the same way /home is

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ok, so what happens if I use that? Is my `Users\Oliver` folder replaced with one assigned to me on the domain controller? Or only the Roaming profile? I still have a hard time imagining what it actually does.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98706 this is an example of it in use. I need to do a little more digging before i can post a coherent answer to what that actually means ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> /home = This net use command option maps the current user's home directory to either the devicename drive letter or the next available drive letter with *.

The basic Net Use command tells your workstation to log you on to a given file server and grant you access to a particular share via a drive letter. The command

```
net use N: \\myserver\stuff
```

tells your workstation to contact the myserver system, grant you access to a share on that server called \stuff, and create an imaginary drive N, through which you can access the data on that share. Now, let's start our in-depth look at Net Use with three quick enhancements to that example.

For example, suppose your home directory is on myserver, in a share named \homedirs, in a folder named \georgehome. You could map drive letter H directly to the \georgehome folder by typing

```
net use H: \\myserver\homedirs\georgehome
```

`/home` is just a quick way to tell `net use` to connect the user's home directory specified in the users Active Directory user record.

[Source](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/permissions/get-the-most-out-of-net-use)

Comment: *"Unfortunately, however, Net Use /home won't reach to a folder in a share"* AFAIK, starting with Windows 2000 it will.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know. Removing it from answer.